# How can I generate datetime data at 5 minutes interval from start date and fill the column?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Generate the following output and where the timestamp is at 5 minutes interval starting from a start date and will end at an end date and the placeID needs to be random.(between 1 to 4) using SQL server.

--Creating data base ; name of the database PARKINGDATA for better understanding

```
Create database parkingdata;

use parkingdata;

CREATE Table marketplace
(

   MarketPlaceId nvarchar,
   DateTimeStamp datetime,

)

--drop table marketplace;

SELECT * from marketplace;




Declare @RandomMarketPlaceID int;
Declare @RandomDateTimeStamp datetime;

Declare @IdLowerLimitNumber int;
Declare @IdUpperLimitNumber int;

Set @IdLowerLimitNumber = 1
Set @IdUpperLimitNumber = 4



DECLARE @start DATETIME = '2015-01-01 00:00:00';
DECLARE @end DATETIME = '2015-03-05 00:00:00';
DECLARE @minuteInterval INT = 5;

DECLARE @countNum INT = DATEDIFF(MINUTE, @start, @end) / @minuteInterval + 1;


Declare @count int
Set @count = 1

While @count <= 20000
Begin 

    Select @RandomMarketPlaceID = Round(((@IdUpperLimitNumber - @IdLowerLimitNumber) * Rand()) + 
    @IdLowerLimitNumber, 0)

    WITH N1 AS (SELECT N = 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1), -- 2
         N2 AS (SELECT N = 1 FROM N1 CROSS JOIN N1 AS N), -- 4
         N3 AS (SELECT N = 1 FROM N2 CROSS JOIN N2 AS N), -- 16
         N4 AS (SELECT N = 1 FROM N3 CROSS JOIN N3 AS N), -- 256
         N5 AS (SELECT N = 1 FROM N4 CROSS JOIN N4 AS N),  -- 65536
         Numbers AS (SELECT Number = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) FROM N5)
    SELECT @RandomDateTimeStamp= DATEADD(MINUTE, @minuteInterval * (Numbers.Number - 1), @start)
        FROM Numbers
        WHERE Numbers.Number <= @countNum;


    Insert Into marketplace values (@RandomMarketPlaceID, @RandomDateTimeStamp)

    Print @count
    Set @count = @count + 1
End


Required OUTPUT Should be:

MarketPlaceID      DateTimestamp
3                  2015-01-01 00:00:00
2                  2015-01-01 00:05:00
4                  2015-01-01 00:10:00
1                  2015-01-01 00:15:00
2                  2015-01-01 00:20:00
.
.
.
.till the end date.
```

Generate the following output and where the timestamp is at 5 minutes interval starting from a start date and will end at an end date and the placeID needs to be random.(between 1 to 4)

Comment: Are you using MySQL or MS SQL Server?

Comment: I am using SQL server.

Answer (score 1):

Do we really need the table `Number` because we can achieve the desired results by using `@countNum` in the loop?
try the following:

```
While @count <= @countNum
Begin 

    Select @RandomMarketPlaceID = Round(((@IdUpperLimitNumber - @IdLowerLimitNumber) * Rand()) + @IdLowerLimitNumber, 0)

    SELECT @RandomDateTimeStamp = DATEADD(MINUTE, @minuteInterval * @count, @start);

    Insert Into marketplace values (@RandomMarketPlaceID, @RandomDateTimeStamp)

    Set @count = @count + 1
End
```

Please find the demo **[here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=7e87f496e7050315eaee5897b2b3dfe5)**.

Comment: @AnirbanSom gr8, you can accept the answer if that helped you resolve the issue.